# Using exception to control code flow

Tags: python, exception

afaik using exceptions to handle code flow is wrong. I'm working in a code that has a method named getEntity(id) and getEntity throws a DoesNotExist exception when entity is not found. There is no entityExists(id) method. To check if a entity exists, code usually does:

```
try: 
   getEntity(id)
catch DoesNotExist as e:
   # entity does not exist
```

It seems to me this would be better:

```
if not entityExists(id):
   # entity does not exist
```

This ^ is common sense? I think the code is like that because it uses Django and it is copying Django exception name (DoesNotExist) and its usual way of handling the inexistence of an entity.

The question is not specific to Python, but the code I'm using as example is in Python, therefore I've tagged the question with Python.

Comment: Exceptions should not be used for control flow yes. But your question is rather general and it depends on a variety of factors what approach is best. In Python try/except is quite common, in some other languages that's not encouraged.

Comment: Using exceptions to handle flow control in Python is not at all wrong: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp

Comment: Further lengthy philosophising and ranting here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351110/are-exceptions-for-flow-control-best-practice-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is known as [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) or *Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission*. From [The Python Glossary](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html):

> This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many `try` and `except` statements. The technique contrasts with the [LBYL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) style common to many other languages such as [c](/questions/tagged/c).

[LBYL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) means *Look before you leap*. Again from [The Python Glossary](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html):

> This coding style explicitly tests for pre-conditions before making calls or lookups. This style contrasts with the EAFP approach and is characterized by the presence of many if statements.

It then goes on to give a good counter-example to your `if not entityExists(id):` suggestion:

> In a multi-threaded environment, the LBYL approach can risk introducing a race condition between “the looking” and “the leaping”. For example, the code, `if key in mapping: return mapping[key]` can fail if another thread removes key from mapping after the test, but before the lookup. This issue can be solved with locks or by using the EAFP approach.

When writing in Python (or any language), it helps to follow the *idioms* of that language, this makes your code easier to grok by others who read it.

Comment: I'd like to add that exceptions in Python are designed to be light-weight so that throwing one (and catching it) is about as costly as other flow control statements; this is different from other languages (e. g. Java) in which raising exceptions is much more costly so that they are not supposed to be used, e. g., in a loop.

Comment: So, the question, even if asked in a general way, can only be answered in a more specific way.  In Python do it like this — in Java do it differently.

Comment: Reading more about EAFP/LBYL, I noticed this is a controversial question, even if you try to simplify the debate ignoring programming languages idioms and performance issues. There is no common and obvious conclusion, as in other programming debates (eg return codes vs exceptions). It seems to me the best thing is to analyze programming language independent/specific pros/cons and choose the best for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it depends on the context. If you know *for sure* of all possible outcomes, go ahead and do your if/elses ([LBYL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl)). If you are unsure of the possible outcomes (for example when dealing with a variable of an unknown type), try/catch ([EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)) is a much safer way to go.